# Getting Error while try to login with Google+ Account in Device [CodenameOne]

Tags: codenameone, google-signin

am getting error while trying to login with google + account on device, but everything is working fine on simulator. please help me on this.
Below is my code and attachment of Error on device.

```
private Login googleLogin=GoogleConnect.getInstance();

private void google_signIn()
{
    googleLogin.setClientId("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com");
    googleLogin.setRedirectURI("http://www.example.com");
    googleLogin.setClientSecret("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    try{    

        if(googleLogin.isNativeLoginSupported()){
            if(!googleLogin.isUserLoggedIn())
            {
                googleLogin.doLogin();
            }
            AccessToken at= googleLogin.getAccessToken();
            token.setToken(at.getToken(), "google");
            profile.setProfileData(token.getToken(), token.getTokenType());
            showForm("games_screen", null);
        }

        googleLogin.setCallback(new LoginCallback() {
            @Override
            public void loginFailed(String errorMessage) {
                Dialog.show("Login Faild", "Retry Login", "Retry", null);
                google_signIn();
            }

            @Override
            public void loginSuccessful() {
                AccessToken at= googleLogin.getAccessToken();
                token.setToken(at.getToken(), "google");
                profile.setProfileData(token.getToken(), token.getTokenType());
                showForm("games_screen", null);
            }

        });
        if(!googleLogin.isUserLoggedIn())
        {
            googleLogin.doLogin();
        }
        else{
            AccessToken at= googleLogin.getAccessToken();
            token.setToken(at.getToken(), "google");
            profile.setProfileData(token.getToken(), token.getTokenType());
            showForm("games_screen", null);
        }   
    } catch (Exception e){        
        Dialog.show("Error", "An error occurred while logging in: " + e.getMessage(), "OK", null);
    }
}
```

[error screen attachment is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIsnJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a DNS error. What's your connection parameters ?

Comment: Agreed, he should make sure to configure his proxy settings for Java so the VM can connect to google